# WHILE loop in DBeaver giving syntax error

Tags: sql, loops, while-loop, dbeaver

I am trying to create a procedure in DBeaver that simply fetches some values as parameters from a datatable (here named 'tempTable') and uses them in a loop to fetch data from another datatable (here 'oldTable), run some calculations and push the new data to the final datatable (here 'newTable).

The tempTable has multiple rows so I was thinking of setting up a loop. However, for some reason every attempt has failed (I have tried various syntax for WHILE and even tried with FOR but without success). Here is my code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`xxx`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `xxx`.`xxx`
BEGIN
    SET @counter = 1;
    WHILE (@counter <= 10)
        LOOP
        SET @tld_temp = (SELECT tld_iter FROM tempTable t WHERE t.ident = @counter);
        SET @country_temp = (SELECT country_iter FROM tempTable t WHERE t.ident = @counter);
        SET @device_temp = (SELECT device_iter FROM tempTable t WHERE t.ident = @counter);
        SET @ttype_temp = (SELECT ttype_iter FROM tempTable t WHERE t.ident = @counter);
        SET @url = CONCAT('%www.xxxxx.', @tld_temp, '/', @ttype_temp, '%');
        
        INSERT INTO newTable(yr, mon, page, query, agg_impr, avg_pos, 
                                                  country, device, ttype, tld)
        SELECT extract(year from date) as yr, extract(month from date) as mon,
        page, query, sum(impressions) as agg_impr, avg(position) as avg_pos, 
        @country_temp, @device_temp, @ttype_temp, @tld_temp
        FROM oldTable g
        WHERE g.device = @device_temp
        AND g.page LIKE @url
        AND g.country = @country
        group by page, query, extract(year from date), extract(month from date)
        order by yr, mon;
        SET @counter = @counter + 1;
    END LOOP;
END
```

You can check the error message in the link below:
[Error message from DBeaver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0oKl.jpg)

Also to be more detailed. The oldTable has various dimensions (country, tld, device, etc.) and metrics (impressions, clicks, etc.) from organic data (Google Search Console). I need to be able to input the desired variations of specific dimensions to the tempTable and the script fetch these row by row as parameters, retrieve the respective data from the oldTable, do some calculations and push the calculated data to the newTable.

i.e.
**tempTable**
[ident country device]
1     france  mobile,
2     france  desktop,
3     germany mobile

the script iterates the tempTable and uses the values of each row as parameters to select the respective data from oldTable.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What are you trying to accomplish functionally? Where is the code failing and with what error message?

Comment: Tag your question with the *database* you are using.  DBeaver is a GUI for passing code to many different databases.